# React child function argument proptype check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

How should check child function arguments `proptype`?

If we have wrapper component like:

```js
const FirstInnerComponent = () => (<div>1</div>);
const SecondInnerComponent = () => (<div>2</div>);

const WrapperOne = ({ children }) => (
  <Container className="fixed">{children(FirstInnerComponent, SecondInnerComponent)}</Container>
);
```

And when we use it:

```js
<WrapperOne>
  {(FirstInner, SecondInner) => (
    <>
      <FirstInner />
      <SecondInner />
    </>
  )}
</WrapperOne>
```

If our `FirstInnerComponent` has propTypes like this:

```js
FirstInnerComponent.propTypes = {
  someProp: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

As we expect we should call `FirstInnerComponent` with forced `someProp`. But how we should use propType for it?

Answer (score 1):

```
FirstInnerComponent.propTypes = {
  someProp: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

this mean you should call `FirstInnerComponent` with a parameter by name `someProp` as string and `required` but if you don't want to use it compiler don't raise error but if you see your console you will see a `red line warning` even if you use it as a array or object again you will see `red line warning`.

another word

> PropTypes exports a range of validators that can be used to make sure
>   the data you receive is valid

Comment: are you sure `vscode` supports this type of coding ?

Comment: Exactly, I'm using it for large scale projects, see here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson